# iOS: WebViewJavascriptBridge callbaks

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm trying to implement call back from html to WebViewJavascriptBridge using (HTML) drop down menu like this:

```
<h2 id="headline">Test</h2>
<select id="selector">
    <option value="systemVersion" selected>iOS Version</option>
    <option value="systemName">System Name</option>
    <option value="name">Device Name</option>
    <option value="model">Device Model</option>
    <option value="userInterfaceIdiom">User Interface</option>
    <option value="identifierForVendor">Vendor ID</option>
</select>
<script>
var headline = $("#headline");
var selection = $("#selector");
</script>
```

But my problems I can not figure out how to pass the values of headline and selection to WebViewJavascriptBridge.

Any of you knows how can I do something like this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`WebViewJavascriptBridge` long time have no maintain.
Maybe you should change to use this library.

[SDBridgeOC](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeOC)

```
 self.bridge.consolePipeBlock = ^(id  _Nonnull water) {
        NSLog(@"Next line is javascript console.log------>>>>");
        NSLog(@"%@",water);
    };
```

This can easy to get javascript console.log.

Also have Swift language Version.

[SDBridgeSwift](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeSwift)

```
bridge.consolePipeClosure = { water in
         guard let jsConsoleLog = water else {
             print("Javascript console.log give native is nil!")
              return
         }
         print("Next line is Javascript console.log----->>>>>>>")
         print(jsConsoleLog)
      }
```